# Tokbox on IOS pause video "getRenderer().onPause"

Tags: ios, video-streaming, opentok, tokbox, remote-assistance

I am looking for a method on IOS (swift) OpenTok SDK

```
 mSubscriber.getRenderer().onPause();
```

I need this for to pause or hold video frame when Subscriber side touch the screen. In my app just the Publisher side sends video. After, when the Subscriber stops to touching screen, video receiving continue with ;

```
mSubscriber.getRenderer().onResume();
```

I didin't find neither "onPause()" nor "onResume" or "getRenderer" on IOS platform OpenTok SDK.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Those functions seem specific to the Android SDK and match up with the Android event lifecycle. For details about iOS, you can check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48218890/9824067

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found on IOS;

```
otPublisher?.videoCapture?.stop()
```

and

```
otPublisher?.videoCapture?.start()
```

These are working.